# Springboot websocket with Kotlin, JS client not working

Tags: javascript, spring-boot, kotlin, spring-websocket

I am following a simple [tutorial](https://github.com/dailycodebuffer/Spring-MVC-Tutorials/tree/master/spring-websocket), but I am doing it in kotlin, I don't think that matters that much,
I tried different configurations but nothing is working for me, I am new to JS
here is what the error looks like.
I must be missing something silly, couldn't figure out what.
[image]
and there is my folder straucture
[image]

this is my configuration

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
class WebSocketConfig: WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {
    override fun registerStompEndpoints(registry: StompEndpointRegistry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/stomp-endpoint")
            .withSockJS()
    }

    override fun configureMessageBroker(registry: MessageBrokerRegistry) {
        registry.enableSimpleBroker("/topic")
        registry.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app")
    }
}
```

I tried using "webjars-locator" dependency with the following configuration.

```
@Configuration
class WebConfig : WebMvcConfigurer {
    override fun addResourceHandlers(registry: ResourceHandlerRegistry) {
        registry
            .addResourceHandler("/webjars/**")
            .addResourceLocations("/webjars/")
    }
}
```

Comment: The tutorial you linked placed the static assets in the  `src/main/resources/static` folder. You clearly are not following the tutorial.

Comment: Have you added [`webjars-locator-core`](https://github.com/dailycodebuffer/Spring-MVC-Tutorials/blob/37893a96936e700fc8b2e7e13cf5e95135cd22e5/spring-websocket/pom.xml#L38) to you class path (pom.xml/build.gradle/...)?

Comment: yes, I did add webjars-locator-core @xerx593

Comment: @RandyCasburn, sorry the screenshot doesn't show the full path, I double-checked and it is placed src/main/resources/static path